# How to get timeago.js to update automatically

Tags: javascript, blogs, timeago

I am trying to create a blog site and use time ago to create a relative time stamp to when the a post is created.

I have it working but the time does not update automatically or at all for a fact

Does anyone know how to get it to update automatically

Here is my code:

```
msgDate = jQuery.timeago(new Date());
$("#centerDiv").prepend("<div id='postInner'><div id='timeStamp'>" + msgDate + "</div></div>")
```

Comment: why are you using `new Date()` inside of `timeago` function? Shouldn't it be set to the date the article was created?

Comment: its my first time using this plugin it seems to work this way, but doesnt update after the article is created. It will say "less than a minute" even though it was posted over an hour ago

Comment: yeah, that's what will happen, because you're setting it to the current date. That's what `new Date()` does, it gives a Date object representing the current date, not the time the article was created

Comment: new Date() is called when the article is created. Read and understand the code before commenting.

Comment: you seem to be calling `new Date()` every time this script runs. To store it, you'd need to be using a server-side language, which you aren't, so I can see that you're doing something wrong

Comment: That is the whole point new Date() is supposed to be called everytime in order to create a timestamp of when the post is created

Comment: No. That's not how it works. `jQuery.timeago` returns how long it has been since the timestamp you passed to it. If you pass it the current date, well, the current date is...less than a minute ago. You need to pass it how long ago you posted the article, if I understand what you're trying to achieve (show users how long it's been since a post is created)

Answer (score 3):

timeago doesn't automagically set a timer to update your HTML.
You'll have to use `setInterval` to create a timer that will update the time stamp.

Example:

```
// Insert your HTML:
$("#centerDiv").prepend("<div id='postInner'><div id='timeStamp'></div></div>")

// Get the timestamp:
var msgDate = new Date();

// Update now, and again every minute:
updateTimeStamp();
setInterval(updateTimeStamp, 60000);
function updateTimeStamp() {
    // Update the text with the elapsed time:
    var timeAgo = jQuery.timeago(msgDate);
    $("#timeStamp").text(timeAgo);
}
```

Comment: Would personally interval it once a minute. Plugin won't show seconds. At launch i won't use new Date(); but the post-date, so i guess he needs to fetch the correct date :)

Comment: They are now working in opposite order.. the new posts are saying they are created earlier than the older posts